# How to Accomplish a Where on a joined table with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following 2 tables in my database:

```
[Schedule](
    [Time] [datetime] NULL,
    [ScheduleID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [PatientID] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Schedule] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ScheduleID] ASC
)
```

and:

```
[Patient](
    [NameLast] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [NameMiddle] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [NameFirst] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [DOB] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [PatientID] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Patient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [PatientID] ASC
)
```

And I want to accomplish the following SQL, except using linq methods with Entity Framework:

```
select NameFirst, NameLast, DOB
from Patient
join Schedule on Schedule.PatientID = Patient.PatientID
where Schedule.Time < GETDATE()
```

I know how to create a join, using my mappings, so creating a join isn't the problem.  I also know how to do the date functionality I need so that isn't the problem.

I need to know how to accomplish (using linq methods) the part that says: `where Schedule.Time < SOMETHING`

Here's what I have tried, but it threw an error:

```
var patients = context.Patient
    .Include(x =>
        x.Schedule.Where(y => y.Time < DateTime.Now)
    );
```

The error it gave me was:  "The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type."

So, how can I accomplish a "Where" on a joined table, like I can in SQL, using linq methods with Entity Framework?

I can't do `context.Patients.Where(x => x.Schedules.Time == DateTime.Now);` because `Patient.Schedules` is a collection, since this is a one-to-many relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like

```
context.Schedule.Where(y => y.Time < DateTime.Now).Select( s => s.Patient);
```

or

```
context.Patient.Where( p => p.Schedules.Any( s => s.Time < DateTime.Now) );
```

Comment: Wow, that's great!  For some reason it never occurred to me to swap the query, and query starting from the Schedule.  Great Answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
from t1 in db.Patient 
join t2 in db.Schedule on 
t1.PatientId equals t2.PatientId 
where t2.Time<getTime 
select new { t1.NameFirst, t1.NameLast, t1.DOB}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm not sure if it is wise to do the GetDate() inside your query, as an `IQueryable` I think it wouldn't work, and as an `IEnumerable` I'm not sure how many times it would be called during the enumeration.

You could first filter the Schedules you want to use and then do the join.

In small steps:

```
DateTime myDate = GetDate();
var oldSchedules = dbCntext.Schedules.Where(schedule => schedule.Time < myDate);

var requiredResult = dbContext.Patients  // join Patients
    .join(oldSchedules,                  // with the old schedules
    patient => patient.PatientID,        // from patients take PatientID
    schedule => schedule.PatientID<      // from old schedules that PatientID
    (patient, schedule) => new           // when they match, take the recods
    {                                    // to create a new Anonymous type
        NameFirst = patient.NameFirst,   // with the required properties 
        NameLast = patient.NameLast,
        Dob = patient.Dob,
    });
```

Of course you could put this in one statement (except for GetDate())

```
DateTime myDate = GetDate();
var result = dbContext.Schedules
    .Where(schedule => schedule.Time < myDate)
    .Join(dbContext.Patients,
    schedule => schedule.PatientId,
    patient => patient.PatientId,
    (schedule, patient) => new
    {
        ...
    });
```